# Get properties of VB element

Tags: properties, vbscript, element

How can I see what properties an element has in a VB script? Example:

```
Dim list : Set list = CreateObject( "Scripting.Dictionary" )
' ... Fill List ...
WriteListElements list
...

Sub WriteListElements ( list )
    Dim e, le
    For Each e In list
        Set le = list(e)                  ' what properties does le have?
        le.name_of_user_defined_attribut  ' I want to access a property but dont know the exact name
    Next
End Sub
```

I use a Tool with a VBScript API. In that API I can read (user defined) attributes from that Tool. But while running the script I get an error telling me that it does not know the name of that user defined attribut. But I use it in the tool. Now I would like to know which attributes are availble in the array above to see if  the user defined attributes are named specificly.

Comment: Are you looking for something like reflection but for plain old VBscript? If yes, I'm afraid it's not possible. Maybe we ca help you to find an alternative way, if you explain exactly why you want to do that : is it that your 'list' object will never have the same type between calls to your WriteListElements() method and thus you cannot know its type?

Comment: If you have PowerShell, you can create an instance of the object there and then use `gm` to get its members: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668321/how-to-use-powershell-get-member-cmdlet

Answer (score 2):

Not really possible.  Only very basic type information is available in the VBScript runtime.  Ideally you could create an adapter that translates your tool's objects into standard Dictionary objects and iterate the Keys.  If that's not possible, the best you can do is check the type name for each object before invoking its members.  Example:

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/vbscript">

    Class Human
        Private m_name

        Public Property Get Name
            Name = m_name
        End Property

        Public Property Let Name(newName)
            m_name = newName
        End Property
    End Class

    Dim joe 
    Set joe = new Human
    joe.Name = "Joe Coder"

    Dim list
    Set list = CreateObject( "Scripting.Dictionary" )
    list.Add "a", 5
    list.Add "b", joe
    list.Add "c", "apples"

    WriteListElements list

    Sub WriteListElements ( list )
        Dim e
        For Each e In list
            If (TypeName(list.Item(e)) = "Human") Then
                document.write("We have found a Human: " &_
                    "<b>" & list.Item(e).Name & "</b>")
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Will you be able to get the list of properties from a script like this?

http://www.vbsedit.com/scripts/misc/wmi/scr_1332.asp

And, you can then use eval() or execute to get the values of these properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim list : Set list = CreateObject( "Scripting.Dictionary" )
' ... Fill List ...
WriteListElements list
...

Sub WriteListElements ( list )
    Dim e, le     
    For Each e In list
        Set le = e.Items                
        Response.Write le(name_of_user_defined_attribut)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easy - use a pseudo reflection:

```
   class Developer

      Public reflection
     '=============================
     'Private properties
      private mId

      private  mFirstName
      private  mLastName

      private sub Class_Initialize()
        reflection = Array("Id","FirstName","LastName")
      end sub

      private sub Class_Terminate()
      end sub

     '=============================
     'public properties

       public property get Id()
          Id = mId
       end property

       public property let Id(val)
          mId = val
       end property


       public property get FirstName()
          FirstName = mFirstName
       end property  

       public property let FirstName(val)
          mFirstName = val
       end property  

       public property get LastName()
          LastName = mLastName
       end property  

       public property let LastName(val)
          mLastName = val
       end property  

    end class


    For each property in obj.reflection 
     document.write(property)
     document.write( Eval ("obj." & property) )
    Next
```