# Get-Member Showing Incorrect Properties When Using Pipes

Tags: powershell

```
wwwroot> $nsmgr.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    XmlNamespaceManager                      System.Object

wwwroot> Get-Member -InputObject $nsmgr

   TypeName: System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager

wwwroot> $nsmgr | Get-Member

   TypeName: System.String
```

It seems like Get-Member is type-converting to a String in first `Get-Member` call, but this seems to be very strange behavior for a Cmdlet like `Get-Member`.

I've read [How to use PowerShell Get-Member cmdlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668321/how-to-use-powershell-get-member-cmdlet) but I don't believe that's the same issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XmlNamespaceManager implements `IEnumerable` so PowerShell will output the items contained within the XmlNamespaceManager down the pipeline. To prevent that you can use the comma operator:

```
,$nsmgr | Get-Member
```

This will create a simple array wrapper around the XmlNamespaceManager so that it gets propagated down the pipe instead of its contents.